# SQL Query multiple if else condition block

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have created sql proc for selecting record from database 
It executes successfully but not returning anything

Can anyone tell me where I a doing mistake ?

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[bb_EmailSentStatus] 
 @type varchar
AS 
 SET NOCOUNT ON 
 SET XACT_ABORT ON  

 BEGIN TRAN


 IF (@type='pending')
 BEGIN
  SELECT [Mail_Track_Id], [FromName],[FromEmail],[ToName],[ToEmail],[ReplyTo],
         [Subject],[CreatedDate],[ModifiedDate],[Server_Msg],[FromSource] 
  FROM [dbo].[Mail_Track] 
  WHERE Active_Status=1 AND Sent_Status IS NULL
 END
 ELSE IF(@type='failed')
 BEGIN
  SELECT [Mail_Track_Id], [FromName],[FromEmail],[ToName],[ToEmail],[ReplyTo],
         [Subject],[CreatedDate],[ModifiedDate],[Server_Msg],[FromSource] 
  FROM [dbo].[Mail_Track] 
  WHERE Active_Status=1 AND Sent_Status = 0
 END
 ELSE IF(@type='success')
 BEGIN
  SELECT [Mail_Track_Id], [FromName],[FromEmail],[ToName],[ToEmail],[ReplyTo],
         [Subject],[CreatedDate],[ModifiedDate],[Server_Msg],[FromSource] 
  FROM [dbo].[Mail_Track] 
  WHERE Active_Status=1 AND Sent_Status = 1
 END
COMMIT
```

Comment: give your table design

Comment: do you required transaction here?

Comment: You  haven't specified the length for `varchar`

Comment: Please explain clearly what is the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't declared a length for your varchar parameter. Change it to:

```
@type varchar(50)
```

If you don't specify a length, `varchar` takes only 1 character by defalt. As a good habit always remember to explicitly define a length for variable types such as varchar, nvarchar etc.

If you use `convert function` to convert a value to a varchar, nvarchar field, it takes 30 characters by defult but even then as a good habit you should always declare a specific length.

Comment: Nicely spotted. Just to clarify: If you don't specify the length of varchar parameter, any input will be truncated to length 1, and thus none of the IF statements will evaluate to true.

Answer (score 3):

You can also eliminate multiple if else by changing where clause on the basis of parameter

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[Bb_emailsentstatus] @type VARCHAR(10) 
AS 
SET nocount ON 
SET xact_abort ON 


SELECT [mail_track_id], 
             [fromname], 
             [fromemail], 
             [toname], 
             [toemail], 
             [replyto], 
             [subject], 
             [createddate], 
             [modifieddate], 
             [server_msg], 
             [fromsource] 
      FROM   [dbo].[mail_track] 
      WHERE  (@type = 'pending'  AND
                active_status = 1 
                AND sent_status IS NULL )
             OR 
             (@type = 'failed'  AND 
                active_status = 1 
                AND sent_status = 0 )
             OR 
             (@type = 'success'  AND    
                active_status = 1 
             AND sent_status = 1  )
```